# How to combine many functions into a single function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop

I have a dynamic button with looping and I have the onclick attribute function, like below :

```
for (var j=0; j<= 1; j++){ 
  btndisplay= document.createElement("input");
  btndisplay.setAttribute("type", "button");
  btndisplay.setAttribute("style","height:80px;width:60px");
  btndisplay.setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction"+ (j+1) +"(this.name)"); 
  document.getElementById('divButtons'+(j+1)).appendChild(btndisplay);   
}
```

How to simplify many functions as below, into a single function?

```
  function myFunction1(name) 
  { 
    if (document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML==""){
     document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = name; 
    }
  }

  function myFunction2(name) 
  { 
    if (document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML==""){
      document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = name; 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another parameter, one for the `name` and another for the `id`:

```
function myFunction(id, name) 
{
    if ( document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=="" )
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = name; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have created:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input...
...
```

the Function is:

```
function myFunction (that) {
  if(that.innerHTML === "") {
    that.innerHTML = that.name;
  }
}
```